# svnserve with selinux on nfs mount unable to start (Centos8)

Tags: svn, selinux, centos8

might be a silly question. Struggling with my subversion server on a Centos8 with selinux enforced. We have an NFS mount to store the data (`/mnt/data/svn`).

The problem (when selinux is in enforcement mode) is that the service won't start as it has not the permissions to access `/mnt/data/svn`:

```
> service svnserve start # error
> journalctl -xe

systemd[1]: Starting Subversion protocol daemon...
-- Subject: Unit svnserve.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit svnserve.service has begun starting up.
... svnserve[2445049]: svnserve: E000013: Can't check path '/mnt/data/svn': Permission denied
... systemd[1]: svnserve.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
... systemd[1]: svnserve.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
... systemd[1]: Failed to start Subversion protocol daemon.
```

**SVN environment**: `/etc/sysconfig/svnserve`:

```
OPTIONS="-r /mnt/data/svn"
```

**Directory permissions**: Recursive ...

```
drwxr-xr-x. 36 svn svn 4096 Nov 17 16:40 /mnt/data/svn
```

**SE config**: via semanage

```
> semanage fcontext -l | egrep "/mnt/data/svn"
/mnt/data/svn           all files          system_u:object_r:svnserve_content_t:s0 
/mnt/data/svn(/.*)?    all files          system_u:object_r:svnserve_content_t:s0
```

**SE context type**

```
> ls -ldaZ /mnt/data/svn
drwxr-xr-x. 36 svn svn system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0 4096 Nov 17 16:40 /mnt/data/svn
```

Without selinux `enforced` everything works as expected. The problem: cannot add `svnserve_content_t` type to `/mnt/data/svn` via `semanage`:

```
chcon -Rv --user system_u /mnt/data/svn             # fine
chcon -Rv --type svnserve_content_t /mnt/data/svn   # fails
```

Seems `snvserve_content_t` is invalid, or I can't assign `nfs_t` and `svnserve_content_t` at the same time. I am a the end of good ideas. Quite likely there is a super simple solution and I am already super happy for any ideas (disabling selinux enforcement is not an option).

Thank you very much in advance,

R

Comment: Check the audit log.

Comment: Thank you very much @MichaelHampton , that was the hint I needed.

Answer (score 1):

**My solution**

The audit log indeed shows what was going wrong:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1606892987.322:161301): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=2570843 comm="svnserve" name="/" dev="0:46" ino=2131353823 scontext=system_u:system_r:svnserve_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

No permission to `search` the directories. My solution was to write a custom selinux policy module/rule:

```
module svnserve_nfs 1.0;

require {
        type svnserve_t;
        type nfs_t;
        class dir { getattr search read write };
        class file { getattr unlink append open read setattr write lock create rename };
}

#============= svnserve_t ==============
allow svnserve_t nfs_t:dir { getattr search read write };
allow svnserve_t nfs_t:file { getattr unlink append open read setattr write lock create rename };
```

... checked, compiled, installed, works. Might be a bit more restrictive but at the moment I am happy it works as expected.